# /swagger-ui.html is not working, it is showing 404 error

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-status-code-404, swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-ui

While configuring openapi 3 for Spring Boot application, the "/swagger-ui.html" endpoint is not working, it is showing 404 error. Here is the pom.xml file.

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-M4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this dependency for enable swagger ui (openapi 3) specification, for more details refer this [link](https://springdoc.org/#spring-webmvc-support)

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
  <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.13</version>
</dependency>
```

I hope it will work without this dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-M4</version>
</dependency>
```

And swagger ui link will look like this http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html#/

in documentation this is the format http://server:port/context-path/swagger-ui.html
learn more about context path from this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-context-vs-servlet-path#:%7E:text=Simply%20put%2C%20the%20context%20path,%3A%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F)